# R printing variable name, chi-sq loop

Tags: r

I'm new to R, so I'm sure this is pretty simple. This works as a loop printing bivariate tables and chi-squares:

```
results <- lapply(c("age", "female", "black"), 
function(var){
print(table(data$heart,data[,var]));
print(chisq.test(data$heart,data[,var], correct = FALSE))
})
```

For the first variable, it prints the following result:

```
       0    1
  0 1016  977
  1   47   35

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  data$heart and data[, var]
X-squared = 1.2665, df = 1, p-value = 0.2604
```

I just want it to print the *actual* variable names in the table / instead of "data[,var]" in the chi-sq result so I know what I'm looking at.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work

```
fun <- function(var){
    print(table(data$heart,data[,var], dnn = c('heart', paste(var))))
    out <- chisq.test(data$heart,data[,var], correct = FALSE)
    out$data.name <- paste('heart and',var)
    print(out)
}

results <- lapply(c("age", "female", "black"),fun)
```

Comment: I'm actually getting the exact same results -- table with no name and "data[,var]"

Comment: Show some example data

Comment: It works with dnn! The table has names now. It still says 'data:  data$heart and data[, var]' in the Chi-square results, but I can live with that. Thanks!